# concantenating the value of select option in selectize.onchange method to be used in a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, selectize.js

I am working on a project where I created an API in Flask Python and part of the URL has its value gotten from a select option in a Jinja template:

Jinja2 template HTML: values from the backend

```
 <select id="food"
       multiple="multiple">
      <option value="all_food">Show all food</option>
      {% for f in food %}
      <option value="{{f}}">{{f}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

I also used the selectize.js library to render the select option because I would like to filter the options with a search and select multiple values if the user pleases
Javascript looks like:

//The selectize library

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  let $myfood = $('#food').selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Select a your favorite dish..",
    onChange: (value) => {
         return food(value)
    }
  });
```

//Function

```
  async function food(selected_food) {
    // Using the Fetch function we will get the data
    const url = `/myAdmin/fooAnaly/get_food_data/${selected_food}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const datapoints = await response.json();
    }
```

Everything if the user selects one option at a time but not when the user selects multiple value. So i tried to concantenate the options with .join() method on multiselect value in order to convert it to string in the onchange method of selectize but I got an error.

```
onChange: (value) => {
          let conc_val = $(this).val().join('&')
         return food(conc_val)
    }
```

error:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).join is not a function
```

I expected the conc_val to return a string that looks like this:

```
"<foodoption1>&<foodoption2>&<foodoption3>"
```

So that URL can look like this in the backend(flask):

```
 "/myAdmin/fooAnaly/get_food_data/<foodoption1>&<foodoption2>&<foodoption3>"
```

I can then split it with the '&' in python.

I have tried to create an empty array and try to push the values and then loop through but that did not work maybe I am not on the right track here. Please how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Rather than joining `$(this).val()`, you should try joining the `value` parameter that is passed in to the onChange function.

Comment: @James Thank you. It worked like this onChange: (value) => {
        let conc_food_val = ''
        conc_food_val += value.join('&')
         return food(conc_food_val)
    }